# Predicting when there are many missing values in independent variable

Tags: regression, forecasting, data-transformation, missing-data, data-preprocessing

I have past movie ticket bookings data. Tickets for each movie show starts getting sold at least 15 days before the day of show. There are days when tickets don't get sold at all! My goal is to predict final tickets that will be sold based on tickets that has been sold so far. Below is how my data looks like

[image]

As you can see there are missing values in the second column which appear as 0, my cumulative series starts from 0. My problem is there are way too many 0 values or missing values and the data i presented is too idealistic. For certain dates, tickets start getting booked from 8th day onwards. So there will be 0 starting from 15 till 9th day! If i fit a regression by including seasonality variables, it does not give me a good r square. Can anyone suggest how to handle this kind of missing data or if i am missing anything?

Comment: You want to predict a *general* relationship, lumping data in from different shows? Or a show-*specific* relationship? (Is your data set the table you show or is that just "one instance"?)

Comment: Data i posted is just one instance. There are many such dates. Given this, i want to use this pattern for predicting for future. So if i have past 2 years ticket booking data then i can build a model that predicts total tickets sold given all these input parameters. Now for a future day i can use this model for predicting how many final tickets i can sell. So for the show date 24/08/2016 if i want to predict how many final tickets will be sold on 22/08/2016 then i will use input parameters day_before_show=2, lets imagine ticket_sold=4 and cumulative_series=49. Now predict final_ticket_sold

Comment: This is historical data which i posted

Comment: In that case, you should consider broadening your question to focus more on what your data is and what you want to predict. I am skeptical that "days before show" is really sufficient. I would think you would want to consider ticket sales for previous showings of the same movie (if that is available), or days since the premier of that movie. Even if this additional data is not available, you would want to consider what day of the week the show is on, at least.

Comment: @GeoMatt22, what if movie is shown only once and we don't have data for the same movie? Also, the last sentence you mentioned is broadly called as 'seasonality', which i did add towards the end of the question. Let me know if you need any further information. Thanks!

Comment: the main point of my comment was you should clarify your question*, which is broader than "handle missing data". Note that below you already got one overly narrow answer because your question was not clear. (*question = above, not in the comments). You should summarize your complete data set (how many shows? over what historical period? is the lead up always 15 days?). You should also summarize the model you tried which was unsatisfactory (using variable symbols and equations).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle missing data depending on how much effort you want to put into it. I stumbled into R package (DmWR) that presents several options including interpolation, knn and others.

Comment: I am not looking for technique for treating missing values. There are plenty such techniques. I am looking for an approach on how to approach this problem better. If i blindly treat missing values and in real world it comes out that there are days when you do not get any ticket sales, then model will be wrong all together. So my point is how can i make the model represent the real world scenario and at the same time give good predictive accuracy. Thanks!